# Динамическое обновление диаграммы PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qchartview

Я строю диаграмму в *PyQt5*, код приведен ниже. 
Главное окно связано с другой программой через *TCP/IP* протокол, данные "ловятся" с помощью функции `add_table`. Данная функция связана с другим классом, из которого приходит сигнал, о том что поступили новые данные с помощью аттрибута `parser.data_signal = 1`.

Я пытаюсь добавить новые данные на диграмму с помощью 
`self.series.append('New data', 5)`, но диаграмма не обновляется.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать. Извиняюсь за не совсем репрезентативный пример кода)

```
from PyQt5 import QtChart
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQtChart Pie Chart")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 600)
        self.show()
        self.create_piechart()
        add_data_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.add_table)
        add_data_thread.start()

    def create_piechart(self):
        series = QtChart.QPieSeries()
        series.append("Python", 80)
        series.append("C++", 70)
        series.append("Java", 50)
        series.append("C#", 40)
        series.append("PHP", 30)
        series.setLabelsVisible(True)

        series.setLabelsPosition(QtChart.QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)
        for slice in series.slices():
            slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setTitle("Pie Chart Example")
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chart.legend().markers(series)[0].setLabel("Python")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[1].setLabel("C++")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[2].setLabel("Java")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[3].setLabel("C#")
        chart.legend().markers(series)[4].setLabel("PHP")

        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartview)

def add_table(self):
    while True:
         if parser.data_signal == 1:
             self.add_to_table(self.parser.data)
             parser.data_signal = 0
             self.series.append('New data', 5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
#import threading
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QPieSeries, QPieSlice
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal


class MyThread(QThread):                                                       # +++
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # где-то тут ваша функция, из которого приходит сигнал,            # !!1
            i = random.randint(0, 1)
            self.mysignal.emit(i)
            self.msleep(2000)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQtChart Pie Chart")
        self.create_piechart()
        
#        add_data_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.add_table)
#        add_data_thread.start()
        self.mythread = MyThread()                                             # +++
        self.mythread.mysignal.connect(self.add_table)                         # +++
        self.mythread.start()                                                  # +++


    def create_piechart(self):
        self.series = QPieSeries()
        self.series.append("Python", 80)
        self.series.append("C++", 70)
        self.series.append("Java", 50)
        self.series.append("C#", 40)
        self.series.append("PHP", 30)
        self.series.setLabelsVisible(True)

        self.series.setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)
        for slice in self.series.slices():
            slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))

        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.series)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self.chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        self.chart.setTitle("Pie Chart Example")
        self.chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        self.chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[0].setLabel("Python")
        self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[1].setLabel("C++")
        self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[2].setLabel("Java")
        self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[3].setLabel("C#")
        self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[4].setLabel("PHP")
        
        self.num_data = 5                                                      # +++

        self.chartview = QChartView(self.chart)
        self.chartview.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.chartview)

    def add_table(self, value):
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if value:
            self.series.remove(self.series.slices()[0])

            _slice = QPieSlice(f'New data {self.num_data}', random.randint(5, 30), self.series)
            _slice.setBrush(QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)]) )
            _slice.setLabelVisible(True)
            self.series.append(_slice) 

            for slice in self.series.slices():
                slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))
            self.series.setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice.LabelInsideNormal)
            self.chart.legend().markers(self.series)[4].setLabel(f'New_data: {self.num_data}')
            
            self.num_data += 1
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(500, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не работает, если функция, получающая данных подключается к сокету по TCP/IP протоколу.

Comment: @follow_the_sun я не понимаю, что у вас не работает.

Comment: Я вставляю в качестве функции, принимающей данные следующее( ф-ция вызывается в классе MyThread):
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
 PORT = 12345      
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            s.listen()
            msg_size = 0
            while True:
                print(123)
                try:
                    conn, addr = s.accept()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    request.close()
                    break
                else:
                    request = conn.recv(1024)

Comment: В классе MyThread mysignal наследуется от list:

mysignal= pyqtSignal(list)

Когда данные получены в виде списка data:

self.mysignal.emit(data)